# Performance testing on JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to do performance testing on JMeter with uploading 20000 Images files with Approx 40-50 concurrent login users.
And after that 1000000 Images files with Approx 450-500 concurrent login users.
Size of each image is around 900KB.

Can any one suggest me is it possible through JMeter or any other open source tool?

If JMeter is fine then:

1. How we can pick these images from FTP location and store in DB after login by user and number of users I have mentioned above?

2. How Users will login one-by-one in to application?

3. What is the best way to test this kind of scenario i.e. on distributed machines or single machine?

If any one have best way, kindly share it with me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Jmeter.

For 450-500 concurrent logins, you'll either want to run JMeter on a server, or on a cluster of machines to keep the input/output from choking itself.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by Jmeter either by creating severel threads and takes data (i.e. imagename, userid...)  from external csv file.